# cannot get rid of some padding

Tags: css, html

I have an image inside an anchor tag. I would like the image to have a thick gray border, and when I hover it with the mouse the image should be surrounded by a thin black border, that doe not cover the gray border completely. I implemented this idea with two borders: the image has a border and the anchor has another border. In my understanding should work fine but it does not: there is a sort of padding margin in the bottom side of the image. Am I doing something wrong with the styles ? Here is the code I use, just copy and paste it to see it yourself:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            a img {border:1px #cccccc solid}
            a:hover img {border:1px #000000 solid}
            a {float:left;border:2px #cccccc solid}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href=""><img src="https://sites.google.com/site/davikokar/lavaligiafelice/puglia2012/thumbs/IMG_7861_2_3.jpg"/></a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add display:block to the img

http://jsfiddle.net/renekoch/MDy3n/

Answer (score 0):

try removing this line

```
a {float:left;border:2px #cccccc solid}​
```

if your intention is to only highlight the image on hover and it works fine

http://jsfiddle.net/LpPVq/

Answer (score 0):

I'm no wiz at CSS, but it seems you're redefining `a` in CSS line #3